# search option unstable - react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, search, highlight

I have a react native App with a TextInput and Flatlist.
Search something using the TextInput and flatlist filters and displays the search result.
The search texts are highlighted.
Now when I search "signal" as shown below we can see "..." is highlighted telling the user the highlighted text is inside the long message.

[image]

Now when I type "enquiry" why doesn't it do the same ???

[image]
[image: e]

highlight code:

```js
getHighlightedText = text => {

  const {
    value
  } = this.props;

  if (value == "" || value == null || value == 0) {
    return <Text > {
      text
    } < /Text>
  } else {
    const words = value.split(/\s+/g).filter(word => word.length);
    const pattern = words.join('|');
    const tex = escape(pattern);
    const re = new RegExp(tex, 'gi')
    const children = [];
    let before, highlighted, match, pos = 0;
    const matches = text.match(re);

    if (matches != null) {
      for (match of matches) {
        match = re.exec(text)
        if (pos < match.index) {
          before = text.substring(pos, match.index);
          if (before.length) {
            children.push(before)
          }
        }
        highlighted = < Text style = {
          {
            backgroundColor: 'coral'
          }
        }
        key = {
          match.index + match[0].length
        } > {
          match[0]
        } < /Text> 
        children.push(highlighted);
        pos = match.index + match[0].length;
      }
    }

    if (pos < text.length) {
      const last = text.substring(pos);
      children.push(last);
    }
    return <Text > {
      children
    } < /Text>
  }

}


render() {

  return

  <Text > getHighlightedText(text) < /Text>

}
```

What am I doing wrong?? How can I fix this??  Please help stuck with this for days!!!

Update:
case where search text is not on screen.

[image]

Comment: What happens when signal is not visible ?, all your examples signal is visible or at least part of the word is visible

Comment: yes yes. got your point. I have added one more image in my question. "announcement" is searched. the string is not in the short message. it's inside the long text. yet "..." is highlighted.

Comment: Based on your logic you highlight a specific part, have you done anything to hightlight last part when a text is not visible ?

Comment: no no just the specific part

Comment: From what i see the highlight on the '...' happens based on some calculation inside text component. cant figure out the reason

Comment: should I use a key in my render "Text component"??

Comment: I dont think that will help in anyway

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216049/discussion-between-masaladosa-and-guruparan-giritharan).

Comment: @GuruparanGiritharan anyway I can grab that "..." and manually highlight it?? I know "..." is added as default as I have not mentioned ellipsizeMode anywhere. But any workaround???

Comment: What if you change the color of the down arrow ? will be more user friendly as well

Comment: Thats a good idea. Thanks Guru :)